# Secure but not delete data on dead iphone before repair

Tags: iphone, photos.app, repair

My 1st generation iPhone SE is not charging or turning on, there is always a red battery icon when I connect it to a charger. I think the battery is gone, as there have been problems for some time, like the charge would drain very very fast, going from 100% to 40% and then 1% in a short while. However, it was going on like this and I hadn't expected it to die suddenly. My mistake.

Now, I want to send it to some non-Apple repair agents. Most of my data had been backed up on iCloud. However, I did not back up my photos because of space constraints and I would like to have them back.

In this situation, if I remove this device from iCloud, will data like those in Notes, messages, Whatsapp, Gmail and other apps be removed from the phone? However, will the photos stay? Is there any way to protect the photos?

The repair store has said they will need the device pass code in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Which iOS do you have installed on your iPhone? Where are your photographs stored: within the Photos app or somewhere else? How do you access your photographs when you wish to view them on your iPhone? On another note, an Apple-authorized repair shop should not need your passcode to fix the phone. Not sure why others would need it.

Comment: I took it to another third party repair store who didn't ask for these details and repaired in front of me. I am using iOS 15.7.3. My photo are stored in the Photos app and view them using the same. I shall now back them up. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear your phone was fixed. What do you mean when you say "removing the device from iCloud"? How did you plan to remove it?

Comment: I use the same apple id on other devices and from there I have the option of seeing which devices use the same apple id and remove them.